# Is there any order of adding javaScript event listeners?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am pretty new to js.  I am not sure why the following code does not work for `keypress` event. `click` event works though.

```js
//index.js
//Detecting Button Press

var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);
  });
}

//Detecting Keyboard Press

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
    makeSound(event.key);
});


function makeSound(key) {

  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      tom1.play();
      break;

    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();
      break;

    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      tom3.play();
      break;

    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      tom4.play();
      break;

    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      snare.play();
      break;

    case "k":
      var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      crash.play();
      break;

    case "l":
      var kickBass = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      kickBass.play();
      break;

    default:
      console.log(buttonInnerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
<footer>
  Made with ❤️ in London.
</footer>

</html>
```

But if I put the `keypress` eventlistener at the top of the js file as below, it works. Both `keypress` and `click` events work!. There is no jQuery library involved. I have tested on Chrome and firefox.

Is there any order that the event listeners must be added in the javascript file? If not, please explain me the possible reasons.

```js
//index.js
//Detecting Keyboard Press

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
    makeSound(event.key);
});


//Detecting Button Press

var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);
  });
}




function makeSound(key) {

  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      tom1.play();
      break;

    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();
      break;

    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      tom3.play();
      break;

    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      tom4.play();
      break;

    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      snare.play();
      break;

    case "k":
      var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      crash.play();
      break;

    case "l":
      var kickBass = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      kickBass.play();
      break;

    default:
      console.log(buttonInnerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
<footer>
  Made with ❤️ in London.
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: `i <= numberOfDrumButtons` should use `<`. You're accessing outside the array on the last iteration.

Comment: That's why the first one doesn't work. You're getting an error on the last iteration, so the code that adds `keypress` never runs at all. Didn't you see the error message in the console? If you didn't look in the console, why not? That should be your first step when trying to debug JavaScript code.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I saw that error. But I didn't know what it meaned. Thanks for pointing out.